# Exoplayer setPlayWhenReady crash

Tags: android, video, playback, exoplayer

I think I have an issue somewhere in my player class. I noticed this through a crash report SDK embedded in my application. I'm not posting my code for now since the stack trace of the error doesn't seem to be related to any of my code. But I maybe wrong (and surely I am). Here's the stack trace of the crash:

```
com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultControlDispatcher.dispatchSetPlayWhenReady
DefaultControlDispatcher.java - line 28
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player.setPlayWhenReady(boolean)' on a null object reference
com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultControlDispatcher.dispatchSetPlayWhenReady DefaultControlDispatcher.java:28
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerControlView$ComponentListener.onClick PlayerControlView.java:1116
android.view.View.performClick View.java:5265
android.view.View$PerformClick.run View.java:21534
android.os.Handler.handleCallback Handler.java:815
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage Handler.java:104
android.os.Looper.loop Looper.java:207
android.app.ActivityThread.main ActivityThread.java:5896
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Method.java
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run ZygoteInit.java:789
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main ZygoteInit.java:679
```

What I understood is that, in poor connection conditions, the player stops and shows the control view (I was able to replicate this behaviour). When I hit the play button this is what happens.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had no answers I checked by myself until I found the cause of the issue.
The crash was due to the player becoming null after entering some sort of error (it was connection-related issue in my case).
Since the control view is handled by Exo itself, the crash was happening in the library inner classes and I suppose the player was set to null by internal routines. When Exoplayer enters a error state the `Player.DefaultEventListener` that we attached to it enters in the callback `onPlayerError(e: ExoPlaybackException?)`. 
Here I handled the error recreating the player and resuming the stream to the previous seek position (if present) or to the beginning.